# MapViewOfFileEx() returns NULL

Tags: shared-memory, createfile

When I use `MapViewOfFileEx()` to create a map file view of a shared memory file it returns a `NULL` handle.

1. I am trying to open an already existing encrypted file by passing `OPEN_EXISTING` to the method `CreateFile()`.
2. Then I create a file mapping using `m_handle = CreateFileMapping(m_hFile, NULL, protectionFlags, 0, size, NULL);`.
3. Finally `m_p = MapViewOfFileEx(m_handle, dwMapAccess, 0, 0, size, 0);` to create file mapping.

This results in a `NULL` handle for the file. `size` is nearly 3 GB.

`GetLastError` returns 183.

Comment: Show some code, otherwise people would have to guess what kind of parameters you might be passing to the functions listed. Also, did you consult the MSDN in order to find what error 183 is? It is `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` and could be the result of calling `CreateFileMapping` more than once.

Comment: After debugging I noticed that the file size being passed to MapViewOfFileEx() API is more tha 2GB. Is there any restriction on the file  size that can be passed to this API??. The GetLastError() shows 87.

Comment: Code snippet is                                                                                  m_handle = CreateFileMapping( m_hFile, NULL,protectionFlags, 0, size , NULL ); 
m_p = MapViewOfFileEx( m_handle , dwMapAccess, 0, 0, size, 0 );              where size is nearly 3 GB.

Comment: Please consult the table of [System Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). 87 is `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. The size of the mapping cannot exceed the size of the biggest "hole" in the user portion of the virtual address space, which on 32-bit systems is 2 GB (3 GB with the 3/1 tuning). Pass `0` in the 5th parameter to `MapViewOfFileEx` to map the entire file, if it can fit into the virtual address space.

Comment: Hi Hristo,                                                                                                          Thank you for the support. I passed the 5th argument as 0. But now the error code returned is 8 (ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY). Any clue on this??

Comment: The file is too big for the mapping to fit entirely into the virtual address space of the process, which leads to me to the conclusion that either your system is 32-bit or your project is configured to produce a 32-bit executable.

Comment: My executable is 32 bit.

Comment: You cannot map entirely 3 GB of file data into the address space of a 32-bit executable unless either the 3:1 tuning is in place or the executable is large-address aware. Consult the table [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx) as to how much memory is available to 32-bit processes and under various conditions.

Comment: @HristoIliev, Now file size is reduced to 600 MB but still getting same problem . I am getting 87 as error code for MapViewOfFileEx(). Sometimes it fails with error code 8.